# php sort array by 2 or 3 columns, then mingle a little again

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Currently we sort products in a grid by the columns of the grid. First column A, then B then C. Column A can hold the revenue (or the profit) en column B can hold the date the product was added. If we sort by revenue first and then date added the result is a list of high revenue products; products with the same revenue are sorted by date subsequently. The other way around, with first date added and then revenue results in a list sorted by new products first.

**The problem we face is the following**: if we add 100 new products and sort by newest first then the bestsellers are nowhere to be seen on page 1 (but far far down the list). When we sort by bestsellers then new products will never get a chance because the are hardly ever seen and never climb up based on revenue.

**So my question is**: how does one sort an array based on attribute 1, then 2 etc. But after that 'mingles or mixes' the sorting in the above case so we see for example: 1 bestseller, 1 new, 1 bestseller, 1 new .. or similar 1 bestseller, 2 new, 1 bestseller, 2 new ... so you kind of *promote* 1 of the attributes

**Can this be done?**

Below an **example** with the original data, then the 'normal' ssort by revenue and the last grid contains the sort we would like to achieve.

How would one do this? And can this be done either or both in PHP? Or does MySQL have something for this.

I appreciate your help

[image]

Comment: How are you using this data? I ask because the best solution would be based on how much data you are retrieving and how you intend to use it. If you are pulling out thousands of records it would be better to find a solution in MySQL, if it's for a webpage with only 20 products for example using just PHP may give you the best result. Either way you'll need to identify your best sellers and newest products separately and combine them together.

Comment: Difficult. Currently 500-200 products existing in collection array/object (actually Magento). Maybe more in future ;) Maybe the solution is a little more arbitrary when I read my own problem again: because you would need to set some kind of "cutt-off" date from which we consider new so important that it needs to be promoted (but this is in the case of a date in col 2; if it were a text attribute that would make it more difficult). Meaning: we should be lucky the second col is a date and maybe with a cut off we could then 'mark' and 'promote' this particular array elements.

Comment: How about sorting by col A revenue. And setting the same col A value of rows - that had a filter like < then date -  to a random value between max and min of the revenue. I.e. override setting a random value to col A revenue to promote the row?

Answer (score 3):

You can try a purely MySQL based solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @inc1 := IF(@inc1 IS NULL, 1, @inc1 + 1) AS `inc`, `product_id`, ... FROM `products` ORDER BY `sales`
UNION
    SELECT @inc2 := IF(@inc2 IS NULL, 1, @inc2 + 1) AS `inc`, `product_id`, ... FROM `products` WHERE `date_added` > 'yesterday' ORDER BY `date_added`
) AS `tbl` GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY `inc` ASC
```

This gives you an idea, but basically what we're trying to achieve is this, we get all the best sellers first and give them a generated increment number, secondly we do the same but with the latest products... because both data sets increment separately we get the same numbers. Grouping by the product id will get rid of any duplicates (if for example your new product becomes an instant success) and the order by inc will sort them nicely to achieve your mixed result...

well that's the theory anyway! Hopefully this gives you a good start ;)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to order the resultset by custom order MySQL has FIELD() function

```
ORDER BY FIELD(column,'value1','value2','value3')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, ordering by the field doesn't achieve the mixing of the products that are returned.

Comment: @R.Chappell i agree its not clear answer but a part of it. The solution will come with combination of php sorting and the logic based on which sorting is required. There is no clear concise answer without certain simulation.